# Can I add an image to the instructions of a MTurk HIT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I would like to show an example image of how to annotate keypoints within an image for the MTurk worker. Preferably, the example image would show in both the short-instruction and full instructions sections.

I've tried simply putting HTML code within MTurk template for the crowd-keypoint API by inserting a `<img src=" ">` HTML instruction. It says above that any HTML code be inserted.

Here's the current code:

```
<script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js" 
</script>

<crowd-form answer-format="flatten-objects">
    <crowd-keypoint 
        src= ${image_url}
        labels="['Keypoint 1', 
                 'Keypoint 2']"
        header="Place points on the requested item(s)"
        name="annotatedResult">

        <short-instructions>
            <p><img src=”https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg”></p>
            <p>Place points on the requested items.</p>
        </short-instructions>

    </crowd-keypoint>
</crowd-form>
```

I'm just getting a broken image link where I expect the image to appear. The image I'm using one from my own s3 bucket - but in the above code I've just provided a link to some picture. But that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have two minor issues:
1. You're missing the closing '>' on the first line
2. In your image tag it looks like you're using smart (or curly) quotes around the URL of the image. Those often get placed there by Microsoft Word but don't work well with HTML code. If you replace ” with " you should be fine.